# Due to change in environment java new date() function is giving date in 'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MM:SS' format. but only 'DD-MON-YYYY' format is expected

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Recently we migrated java code to OCI environment from AWS environment.
Below is the code which is giving issue.

```
sql.addSQLToWhereClause(XXXTable, "? between table1.start_date and table1.end_date")
            .addSQLToWhereClause(YYYTable, "table1.ORG_ID = ? ")
            .addSQLToWhereClause(XXXTable, "table1.LANG_CODE = ? ")
            .bind(new Date())
            .bind(ConstValues.ORG_ID)
            .bind(locale.toString().toUpperCase());
```

In AWS environment it is working fine, but in OCI environment we are getting error:
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

We are getting this error because .bind(new Date()) is putting '07-JAN-2021 10:49:04' in the first parameter. But expected value is '07-JAN-2021'

Please suggest why this additional information is coming in current date and how can we remove it without changing java code.

Thanks
Rahul

Comment: Is `new Date()` a `java.util.Date` or a `java.sql.Date`?

Answer (score 0):

Object instances of Java's `java.util.Date` class always had the time portion in it. Why it should behave differently on AWS … – no idea!

But I assume that the implementation of `bind(java.util.Date)` is different in those environments, because the implementation of `Date.toString()` will come with a completely different output than that shown in the question.

So please check the version for the library that provides the respective class.